# grunt build generate an error when using auth0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, auth0

I created a mini project using angularjs in local everything works good and no errors in console but after building the project with grunt build nothing works and this is the error :

```
vendor.ce3c01a3.js:2 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <-a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1
at Object.d [as get] (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1
at d (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)
at e (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)
at Object.g [as invoke] (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)
at request (angular-jwt.js:48)
at g (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3(anonymous function) @ vendor.ce3c01a3.js:2
vendor.ce3c01a3.js:2 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:      views/customersReport.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$compile/tpload? p0=views%2FcustomersReport.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1
at i (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at g (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3
at o.$eval (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at o.$digest (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at o.$apply (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:3)
at vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1
at Object.g [as invoke] (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)
at g (vendor.ce3c01a3.js:1)(anonymous function) @ vendor.ce3c01a3.js:2
```

Here is my app.js code :

```
'use strict';

 var app = angular
   .module('sampleapp', [
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngMaterial',
     'ngAria',
     'ngCookies',
     'ngMessages',
     'ngResource',
     'ngRoute',
     'ngSanitize',
     'auth0',
     'angular-storage',
     'angular-jwt'
   ]);

   app.config(function($routeProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider,         $locationProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when( '/createAccount', {
      controller: 'CreateAccountCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin/createAccount.html',
      pageTitle: 'Homepage',
      requiresLogin: true
    })
    .when( '/login', {
      controller: 'LoginCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin/login.html',
      pageTitle: 'Login'
    })
    .when( '/users', {
      controller: 'UserManagementCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin/usersManagment.html',
      pageTitle: 'Account'
    })
    .when( '/adduser', {
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin/addUser.html',
      pageTitle: 'Invite User'
    })
    .when( '/account', {
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/admin/account.html',
      pageTitle: 'My account'
    })
    .when( '/', {
      controller: 'CustomersReportCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/customersReport.html',
      pageTitle: 'Customers Report'
    })
    .when( '/customers/:action/:customerId?', {
      controller: 'CustomersCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/addCustomer.html',
      pageTitle: '{{action}} Customer'
    })

    .when( '/loading', {
      controller: 'LoadingCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/loading.html'
    })
     .when( '/signin', {
      controller: 'SigninCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/signin.html'
    })
    .when( '/myAccount', {
      templateUrl: 'views/myAccount.html',
      pageTitle: 'My Account'

    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/',
      requiresLogin: true
    });


   authProvider.init({
     domain: myDomain,
     clientID: myClientID,
     loginUrl: '/login'
   });

   authProvider.on('loginSuccess', function($location, profilePromise, idToken, store, datastoreUser) {

    console.log("Login Success");

    profilePromise.then(function(profile) {
      store.set('profile', profile);
      store.set('token', idToken);

      datastoreUser.getUserIdentity(profile.email).then(function(result) {
       console.log(result)
       if (result.data.status == "FOUND") {
        $location.path("/");      
         }else{
        $location.path("/createAccount");      

         }
         });

    });

    $location.path("/loading");  
  });

  authProvider.on('loginFailure', function() {
    alert("Error");
  });

  jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function(store) {
    return store.get('token');
  };
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
 });


 app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('cyan', {
    'default': '800', 
    'hue-1': '50', 
    'hue-2': '500', 
    'hue-3': '900'
  })
  // If you specify less than all of the keys, it will inherit from the
  // default shades
    .accentPalette('grey', {
    'default': '50',
    'hue-1' : '200' 
  });
});


  app.run(function($rootScope,$timeout, auth, store, jwtHelper, $location, datastoreDomain, userSession, datastoreUser, $q) {

  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {

  var token = store.get('token');
  if (token) {
    if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
        getUserIdentity()
      }
    } else {
      // Either show the login page or use the refresh token to get a new idToken
      $location.path('/login');
     }
    }

  });

 function getUserIdentity(){

datastoreUser.getUserIdentity(auth.profile.email).then(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
  if (result.data.status == "FOUND") {
    console.log(auth)
   var domainPromise =    datastoreDomain.getById(result.data.identity.domainId).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.data)
     userSession.setDomain(result.data);
    });

    console.log(auth.profile.email)
   var userPromise = datastoreUser.getById(auth.profile.email).then(function(result){

    console.log(result);
     userSession.setUser(result.data.user);

     $rootScope.userIdentity = {
        displayName:   result.data.user.displayName,
        email:  result.data.user.email,
        domainName: result.data.user.domain.name,
        domainPlan: result.data.user.domain.plan,
        userRole:   result.data.user.role,
        imageUrl:   result.data.user.imageUrl
     }

    });

    $q.all([domainPromise, userPromise]).then(function(){
     $location.path("/");
    })

 }else{
  $location.path("/createAccount");

   }
  });
}


});
```

i have tried everything but didn't works

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my problem it was so simple if anyone else got the same issue use this fix to resolve the Unknown Unknown provider: aProvider after Minification.

```
jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['store', function (store) {
    return store.get('token');
}];
```